# package.json actually in JSON, not just JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, heroku

I keep on getting this on my Heroku log "npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript." Here's my package.json file which I thought was in correct JSON until now. Please help.

```
{
    "name": "GWC-Final-Project",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "description": "Girls Who Code web-app",
    "main": "web.js"
}{
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
        "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
        "debug": "~2.2.0",
        "express": "^4.10.2",
        "hbs": "~4.0.0",
        "morgan": "~1.7.0",
        "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
        "socket.io": "^1.4.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a strange message wording, but what you posted above isn't valid JSON. Seems like you'd need to remove the `}{` in the middle and put a comma there (or after the `"web.js"`) instead.

Comment: There are plenty of [JSON validators online](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=json+validator), any one of them will tell you that this is not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

All npm packages contain a file, usually in the project root, called

**[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)** - this file holds various metadata relevant to the project. This file is used to give information to npm that allows it to identify the project as well as handle the project's dependencies.

*It must be actual JSON, not just a JavaScript object literal.*

[Json](http://www.json.org/) is built on two structures:

- A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
- An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

Corrected package.json file :

```
{
    "name": "GWC-Final-Project",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "description": "Girls Who Code web-app",
    "main": "web.js"
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
        "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
        "debug": "~2.2.0",
        "express": "^4.10.2",
        "hbs": "~4.0.0",
        "morgan": "~1.7.0",
        "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
        "socket.io": "^1.4.8"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma between `}{`

```
{
"name": "GWC-Final-Project",
"version": "0.0.0",
"private": true,
"description": "Girls Who Code web-app",
"main": "web.js"
},
{
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.10.2",
    "hbs": "~4.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.8"
}
}
```